# What modes of convergence does the Fourier transform preserve?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Are there are modes of Convergence (i know of Uniformly, $L^1$,a.e. and in measure) that the Fourier transform of the given sequence preserve?

Comment: Sure: the $L^2$ convergence and the Schwartz space convergence. For both these functional spaces the Fourier transform is an automorphism. I don't know if there are more, but these are the most important as far as I know.

Comment: but does this mean that i can apply all relations these modes of Convergence have like $L^1$ implies a.e of a subsequence  to the sequence of Fourier transformed functions?

Comment: Yes but L1 is a bad example. A sequence converging L1 is mapped by the Fourier transform into a sequence converging uniformly.

Comment: Convergence almost everywhere may not even be well defined on the other side of the Fourier transform since there are a.e. defined functions whose Fourier transform is a distribution (think of $x \mapsto e^{i x \xi}$). Even for Schwartzian functions pointwise convergence fails, think of $g_n = g(x - n)$, where $g$ is a normalized Gaussian.

Comment: Regarding your remark on comparison, i will say that the fact that one topology is coarser/finer than other does not imply that the relation is preserved or reversed on the other side of the Fourier transform. But I do not have a counterexample at hand.